# return AsyncTask's result to its instantiation variable

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've constructed a fully work AsyncTask to handle device authorization, but the only catch is I'm having troubling getting the resulting `Bundle` back to its instantiation variable to continue processing in the main activity. Here is the AsyncTask instantiation:

```
Bundle taskResult = new AuthorizeDevice(this).execute(passToAuthroization).get();
```

I've read some literature on the subject and found that the `onPostExecute()` method may have something to do with that, so with that in mind here it is:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result){
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(context, "background process finished: "+result.getString("UDID"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So how do I get that bundle back to the main activity?

Comment: why bundle. i'm not sure. one thing is if you hit an **exception** in **doInBackground** then you get a null in **onPostExecute**

Comment: well the toasts attempt to access `UDID` is just for debugging. I've laid out a predefined way for exceptions to be caught and sent through the bundle so I can inform the user of problems.

Comment: check PravinCG's answer. he is the right. you have to come up with a waiting mechanism or **throw** the bundle somehow from onPostExecute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a callback interface defined like

```
public interface AuthorisationCallback() {
      void onFinish(Bundle bun);
};
```

Implement this interface and do whatever you want with the bundle.

```
AuthorisationCallback mAuthcallback = new AuthorisationCallback() {
    void onFinish(Bundle bun) {
        // Do what ever with the bundle.
    }
};
```

Send its implementations reference to the AsyncTask

```
new AuthorizeDevice(mAuthcallback).execute(passToAuthroization);
```

In onPostexecute() do

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result){
    dialog.dismiss();
    mCallback.onFinish(result);
}
```

Comment: ok, but how can i redirect to another activity from onFinish, i can't pass it the context, or start an intent

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask is a non-blocking call and you cannot get the bundle the way you want. However what you can do is to create an interface in AsyncTask which will tell you when it is done. Something like onTaskComplete and you can pass the resulting bundle there.

Comment: +1 i missed the instansation part. yes AsyncTask is non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

First, look closer at the API.

I would need to see more of your code to know what you're trying to do, but PravinCG is correct, the way you are using the `AsyncTask.execute()`call is incorrect.  If you want the return value, get it from `onPostExecute()`

It looks like you've started with subclassing `AsyncTask<?,?,?>` which is the way to go, if you need access to your Activity, could you not simply place the AsyncTask subclass in your Activity class? This would allow you to access your Activity's methods from within onPostExecute(), which occurs, by design, on the UI Thread. (Again, would need to see more code to know how feasible this is, just putting it out there).
if not, simply pass a reference to your Activity into your AsyncTask Subclass and use a public method to return the Bundle from onPostExecute, or use an Interface as has been suggested...

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `onPostExecute()` method's return type is void. so it does't return anything. so probably you can make `Bundle taskResult` a instance variable and initialise it with `result` in postExecute